# Why is only the (E,E)-isomer obtained in Claisen-Schmidt condensation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aldol-reaction, stereoselectivity

I added 2 equiv of *p*-tolualdehyde to 1 equiv of acetone to make (1*E*, 4*E*)-1,5-di-*p*-tolylpenta-1,4-dien-3-one (NMR backed it up). Why is this the only isomer formed? Just sterics or something more?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

If your Claisen condensation was run with lots of heat (reflux?), as is typical, then you will obtain the thermodynamic product. For the alkenes, the (*E*)-isomer is more thermodynamically stable (because of sterics) so predominates under these conditions.